# Dart SDK version mismatch while installing build_runner

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add `build_runner: ^1.10.2` to `dev_dependencies` in the `pubspec.yaml` file, but I am getting the following error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.9.0.

Because project_name depends on build_runner >=1.10.2 which requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because project_name depends on build_runner >=1.10.2 which requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

I checked the dart website and the latest version of Dart SDK is 2.9.0 while 2.10 is still in dev.

Here's my `flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.959], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.39.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue with the latest releases of dart, analyzer, and flutter creating conflicts with each other, which you can read more about at this [Github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2763). There likely is no real issue with your configuration.

A temporary solution that I've seen is to use a dependency override of the analyzer:

```dart
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.10.0

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 0.39.14
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem after doing some cleaning up of my directories and having downloaded/installed the latest flutter. Bam. Then I realised that version of flutter sits by default on channel stable. After switching to master, it solved my problem, i.e.:

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: As of September 28, 2020, there is no need to switch to the master channel. An update is available to the stable channel as well.

Answer (score 2):

As of September 28, 2020 the latest version of Flutter on `stable` channel no longer has this issue.

Use these commands to upgrade.

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Please tell the version, I have 1.20.4 and the problem still exists. I use `stable` channel and executed `flutter upgrade`, there is not update.

Comment: something is strange with the update,on stable I got  Flutter 1.22.5+Dart 2.10 on master  I got  Flutter 1.20.4+Dart 2.12.. :(